# Remove all values of a key in PostgreSQL hstore

Tags: postgresql-9.3, hstore

How do I delete/remove the *value* of a postgresql hstore column?

I've got a table named `pages` and a column named `settings` - I need to remove the `read_only` *value* (basically, set it to empty string or nil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, pages is the table, setting is the column, and key is what you are setting to null.

`update pages set settings = settings || '"key"=>null'::hstore;`